# HTML onfocus not calling Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, onfocus

So I'm making a kind of like a telltale game using readonly inputs. I'm using onfocus to call a javascript function, but it won't run the function. I'm new to stackoverflow so if you can't see my code, please tell me. Also, I'm coding on Chromebook so the links to the CSS file and JS file are drive links.

EDIT: I think this is a problem on my computer's end since it's working perfectly fine when I run it on here.

EDIT 2: MY GOD I'M AN IDIOT! I misspelled something in the javascript section, something that DIDN'T EVEN MATTER TO MY GAME was MISSPELLED.

```js
var meep = 0;
function changeText() {
    document.getElementById("startInput").blur();
    if (meep === 0) {
        document.getElementById("startInput").value = "'Why are you here?'";
    } else if (meep === 1) {
        document.getElementById("startInput").value = "'I'm not who I used to be...'";
    } else if (meep === 2) {
        document.getElementById("startInput").value = "'I'm looking for Malya,' you say.";
    } else if (meep === 3) {
        document.getElementById("startInput").value = "'I assume that is you.'";    
    } else if (meep === 4) {
        document.getElementById("startInput").value = "...";
        
    }
    meep++;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///media/fuse/drivefs-ba3df23145370ebbe0addbed7174e8b0/root/html/New%20Website/style.css">
<script src="file:///media/fuse/drivefs-ba3df23145370ebbe0addbed7174e8b0/root/html/New%20Website/code.js"></script>

    
    <body>
    <input type="text" class="no-outline" value="'Who are you?'" id="startInput" onfocus="changeText()" readonly>
    <input type="text" class="tutorial" id="tutorial" placeholder="Click on text to change it." readonly>
```

Comment: I also should have said that the drive links didn't seem to matter since it was working before.

Comment: I run your code and focus first input. It's working. Input values change. I edit your code because of your HTML code wrong. I don't understand your issue. Please check edited version and if it's not working. Explain again.

Comment: seems weird to focus a read only input

Comment: ```onfocus``` for input means when someone click on the input field. So if you want it to be on hover. .. you should ```onmouseover``` . and else  onfocus is working good on your code. https://jsfiddle.net/developersbeat/m9rjcsko/

Comment: @epascarello I wanted to make it so that you could click it to change the text without being able to type in it.

Comment: seems like a button would make more sense than a read only text field.

Comment: But it works! Did you read the answers suggesting why it doesn't work on your end?

Comment: @Dalibor I did, and I only now saw the one with my link to the javascript document.

Comment: so did you try removing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, something that didn't matter to my game, I took out of the code for stackoverflow and OF COURSE it was misspelled. So the solution, when making a random variable you don't even need, do NOT spell document as doument.

Answer (score -1):

This works just fine.
If it doesn't work on your machine, please check out the console do you have any errors, because the line

```
<script src="file:///media/fuse/drivefs-ba3df23145370ebbe0addbed7174e8b0/root/html/New%20Website/code.js"></script>
```

could create problems if the script doesn't work right.